# Are there PC monitors with ability to change hardware settings from PC, like brightness?

Tags: display, brightness, contrast

Really curious about the subject possibility. For instance, like we can change brightness on laptops.

I'd like to adjust brightness and contrast at least, from OS. Quickly.

P.S. Unfortunately, the most manufacturers do not allow quick switching with one-click way.

I remember the a one monitor, some gaming one, like ASUS Rog, which has a button for changing presets.

---

**Update 1**: If someone could point me at a brand-new monitor model with hot-button to change its profiles, it will be really appreciated.

**Update 2 (2022-10-04)**: Use ClickMonitorDDC (for years) to control monitor brightness. It works ok. Please be aware, some monitors like Samsung Odyssey G9 with HDR, [does not support DDC](http://www.ddcutil.com/monitor_notes/#samsung-lc49g95t-odyssey-g9).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get Windows 10's built-in brightness control to work on my desktop?](https://superuser.com/q/1373347/241386), [How to adjust monitor's backlight brightness in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/187302/241386)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a quick/automatic way to change monitor brightness at night on Windows 7 or Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/219859/is-there-a-quick-automatic-way-to-change-monitor-brightness-at-night-on-windows)

Comment: “DDC (Display Data Channel) software might bring bad experience. Brightness/Contrast manipulations do affect screen sharing” – No, they don’t. They send commands to the display. It does not affect screen sharing or other displays on the same PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, yes. For example, VGA connections allow this through the [Display Data Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel), which was later extended to cover HDMI and DisplayPort connections as well.

There seem to be [many apps on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+ddc+control) for controlling monitors via DDC, but it's unclear which monitors actually support it (often it used to be supported but just never mentioned in docs). On Linux you would use `gddccontrol`.

Comment: Thx for for this note, useful. Yeah, I was thinking about that as alternative. It's a pity that's not about monitor settings change (as a device).

Comment: Um, what else do you think DDC is controlling if not the monitor hardware?

Comment: maybe it does controlling of hardware, but not the way as expected. Just an example: why screen is dimmed as well when make screen sharing? Obviously, it doesn't work in such way when I just change brightness on a monitory =)

Comment: Also, got issues with my screenshot software. :( Already silently hate this approach... =)

Comment: I've heard of programs which work like that, but that's definitely not DDC.

Comment: Hm... Interesting... Need to debug it.  I can see B/C changes in the monitor settings, by the way. So, you were right about HW changes.

Comment: Did you find out which apps actually control the monitor and which ones fake it?

Comment: Yeah, I did. Well, some software does not use DCC, but graphic output. My Lenovo started glitching and added yellow tint not in right way. It was a cause of getting yellow in all Screenshot Apps. About certain apps in next comment.

Comment: Desktop lighter, don't use DCC. But it's nice to have it to make your monitor more darker (I got not so low brightness on my monitor).

Comment: As main DCC software I use ClickMonitorDCC. Works quite well, and got hotkeys. Maybe not the best, but really good.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern monitor's hardware settings should be controllable from the PC, that's how professional monitor calibration software do calibrations.

There are quite a few brightness adjustment software (as detailed in this [The Windows Club Article)](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/best-brightness-control-software-for-windows) or screen calibration software that can be used to adjust brightness and contrast. I've been using one called ScreenBright for basic screen calibration on and off for a few years now, although it works, it is no longer supported.

Don't forget to check if your monitor's manufacturer has software that can do this as well. Most manufacturers used to ship software alongside their monitors, but that has become extremely rare in the last decade. You can also try to see if you can achieve the desired effect using your graphic's card software's.

Comment: Thx for for this note, useful. It looks like all software are about changing graphic output to a certain monitor, but not monitor settings changes.

Comment: You would need to look for "monitor calibration" tools rather than brightness adjustment software for true monitor settings changes. Using monitor calibration comes with a risk and has limitations, which is why I suggested the other methods for Brightness. You can look at the one mentioned, [Screen Bright (Softpedia download)](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/ScreenBright.shtml) as an example, or other more up-to-date DDC controllers. Keep in mind changes made through DDC will be on top of the monitor controls, it won't change those controls values.

Comment: Perhaps so. Need to play with "calibration" stuff. I just found out DDC does affect screen sharing and screeshot-software :(((

Answer (score 2):

You can get a USB to HDMI passthrough which offers CEC control.

The CEC offer remote control of a variety of function.

> Device Menu Control – allows a component to control the menu system of
>   another component by passing through the user interface (UI) commands

This suggest you can, but other sites suggest you can't to brightness and contrast.  I can't test it right now so I can't say with certainty.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control

Comment: Yeah, that's about hardware stuff. Anyway, it's really good to know. Thank you for this note!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. PC monitor settings can be modified by the PC if the monitor has software in it that permits the settings to be remotely edited. Typically, smart monitors can be configured from the PC by the user.

However, the smart monitor like any other or most other monitor would most often have buttons on the unit itself to manually change settings for display and a power button upon need. That is for fallback purposes.

Comment: Welcome to the community, NaderH! Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I was looking for a one-click solution. So, it's quite rare situation when you have a quick preset switch button on your monitor. So, that's not option to open monitor settings. But DDC solves the problem, as I mentioned I use ClickMonitorDDC app, it helps.